# Cannot send email from django form

Tags: python, django, sendmail

I asked a somewhat similar question but have resolved my initial issue.

I would like to send an email through a form on Django using send_mail. However when I submit the form the email is not sent.

This is my views.py:

```
def assignmentSubs(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        assignment = AssignmentSubs(request.POST)
        if assignment.is_valid():
            subject = 'Assignment submission: {}'.format(assignment.cleaned_data['assignment'])
            from_email = 'emmanuels@thegradientboost.com'
            message = 'Hi, Please note that {} has submitted an assignment for the {} section. We will reach out to you with more detail regarding this submission'.format(assignment.cleaned_data['link'], assignment.cleaned_data['assignment'])
            send_mail(subject,
                      message,
                      from_email,
                      ['emmanuelsibanda21@gmail.com', 'jasmine.des8@gmail.com'],
                      fail_silently=False,)
    return redirect('classroom/home.html')
```

and my form

```
<form method="post" action="views/students.py"  class="validate">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="assignment">Assignment Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="assignment" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="assignmentlink">Link to GitHub Repo</label>
            <input type="text" name="link" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for=""></label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Assignment" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. How you configure the STMP?
2. The action should be the url of `assignmentSubs` view, i think that `views/students.py` is not a valid url.
3. Do you have any error traceback?
4. If you don't have SMTP yet, you can test with console backend putting this in your settings.py: `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'` you email should appear in the console.

Comment: STMP is configured correctly, users receive an email when they signup. I am not getting a traceback. assignmentSub is in views/students.py

Comment: your view `assignmentSubs` is receiving the request? can you show the urls.py associated with the `assignmentSubs` view?

Comment: Oh sorry, I get what you mean now. This is the error I am getting now ValueError at /students/assignmentSubs
ModelForm has no model class specified.

Comment: ok, that is another thing, you miss the model declaration in your `AssignmentSubs` form in the meta class.